# Displaying YAML metadata in PDF file using Uberdoc

Tags: pdf, yaml, markdown, pandoc

Is there a way to get Uberdoc to use the YAML block somehow?  Uberdoc is a kind of build system on top of Pandoc, and Pandoc understands YAML.   I'm generating a PDF on a mac like so:

`uberdoc build -p`

I know I can do a basic title page using `% Some Title\n% Some author`, but I was after YAML if it's possible.

Comment: What does uberdoc have to do with this? I thought uberdoc was a wrapper for pandoc? What happened when you tried to use yaml metadata like normal with pandoc?

Comment: It didn't appear in the final PDF doc.  I assumed that Uberdoc would have _nothing_ to do with it, but it seems to be interfering somehow

Comment: Had a quick skim through the uberdoc code - he's rewritten the pandoc tex template to cut most of the formatting options, but the title chunk seems the same. Run it with `-v` and see what pandoc command it is actually executing - that may help with diagnosing it.

Comment: Also, I notice uberdoc is relying on pandoc's default formatting deduction engine. Try changing your `pandoc_options_pdf` in the cfg file to include `-t pdf+yaml_metadata_block` to force it to include yaml support.

Comment: thanks. I'll report back after a quick check.

Comment: Gah, I clearly hadn't had enough coffee this morning - the option is added to the from, not the to. It's `-f markdown+yaml_metadata_block`